# update specific fields in elasticsearch with flink sql

Tags: elasticsearch, flink-sql

there is only append mode without primary key defined and upsert mode with primary key defined in flink sql elasticsearch connector. but i want to update specific fields but not all of them. i cant use window to get the first value because our source data may be updated after a very long time. we  do that in java like this

```
        IndexRequest indexRequest = Requests.indexRequest()
            .index(index)
            .id(element.getId())
            .source(GSON.toJson(element), XContentType.JSON);

    element.setSpecificField(null);

    requestIndexer.add(new UpdateRequest(
            index,
            element.getId())
                    .doc(GSON.toJson(element), XContentType.JSON)
                    .upsert(indexRequest));
```

is there any way like this in flink sql? thanks all.